# determinant of $n\times n$ matrix (linearity)

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, determinant

With $\mathbf{I}_{n\times n}$ i denote the unit $n\times n$ matrix.

Let $A=(a_{ij})_{i,j=1,...,n}$ be a matrix.

I am interested in the determinant of the matrix

$det(\mathbf{I}_{n\times n}-A)$.

Is it true that

\begin{equation*}
det(\mathbf{I}_{n\times n}-A)=det
\begin{pmatrix}
1-a_{1,1} & a_{1,2} & \cdots & a_{1,n} \\
a_{2,1} & 1-a_{2,2} & \cdots & a_{2,n} \\
\vdots  & \vdots  & \ddots & \vdots  \\
a_{n,1} & a_{n,2} & \cdots & 1-a_{n,n}
\end{pmatrix}
\end{equation*}
\begin{equation*}
=det
\begin{pmatrix}
1 & a_{1,2} & \cdots & a_{1,n} \\
a_{2,1} & 1 & \cdots & a_{2,n} \\
\vdots  & \vdots  & \ddots & \vdots  \\
a_{n,1} & a_{n,2} & \cdots & 1
\end{pmatrix}
-det
\begin{pmatrix}
-a_{1,1} & 0 & \cdots & 0 \\
0 & -a_{2,2} & \cdots & 0 \\
\vdots  & \vdots  & \ddots & \vdots  \\
0 & 0 & \cdots & -a_{n,n}
\end{pmatrix}
\end{equation*}
\begin{equation*}
=det
\begin{pmatrix}
1 & a_{1,2} & \cdots & a_{1,n} \\
a_{2,1} & 1 & \cdots & a_{2,n} \\
\vdots  & \vdots  & \ddots & \vdots  \\
a_{n,1} & a_{n,2} & \cdots & 1
\end{pmatrix}
-\prod_{i=1}^n (-a_{i,i})
\end{equation*}

holds?

Kind regards.

Answer (score 1):

No, you have used $det(A-B)=det(A)-det(B)$ which is wrong in general take $A=\bf{I}_{n \times n}$ and $B=-\bf{I}_{n \times n}$ for a counterexample.